# Spring order beans by class ordering

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, hikaricp

I have two classes and one of the classes should execute first at run-time among-st the two but it's happening the other way around.

First Class:

```
@Configuration
public class A(){
@Bean
public void methodA(){}

@Bean
public void methodB(){
        for(i=0;i<9;i++){
            B b = new B();
            b.setJdbcUrl();
            b.setUsername();
            b.setPassword();
        }
    }
}
```

Second Class:

```
@Configuration
public class B() extends HikariConfig {
@Bean
public HikariDataSource mysqlDataSource(){}

@Bean(name = "someEntityManager")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean mysqlEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {}

@Bean(name = "someTransactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager mysqlTransactionManager(@Qualifier("someEntityManager") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {}
```

Currently the order followed by the Spring is : 
1) b.mysqlDataSource()
2) b.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean mysqlEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder)
3) b.PlatformTransactionManager mysqlTransactionManager(@Qualifier("someEntityManager") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory)
4) a.methodA()
5) a.methodB()

My order should be followed by the Spring as: 
1) a.methodA()
2) a.methodB()
3) b.mysqlDataSource()
4) b.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean mysqlEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder)
5) b.PlatformTransactionManager mysqlTransactionManager(@Qualifier("someEntityManager") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory)

And it must also go through the code where class B is the only one which depends all the url,username and password settings class A, so A must be initiated first.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could give some indication as to what all these methods do and why they have to go in this order. (Also, why are you writing all of these beans by hand since Boot provides the `DataSource`, `EntityManagerFactory`, and `PlatformTransactionManager` automatically?)

Comment: Consider I have 10 database properties and each of them should be configured using "Second Class" . So the "First Class" will fetch all the 10 database properties like url, username and password and will pass these parameters to 10 objects of class B such that 10 Hikari Data sources will be created at run time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @DependsOn:

```
@Configuration
public class A {

    @Bean
    public void methodA() {
    }

    @DependsOn("methodA")    
    @Bean
    public void methodB() {
        for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            B b = new B();
            b.setJdbcUrl();
            b.setUsername();
            b.setPassword();
        }
    }
}

@Configuration
@DependsOn({"methodA", "methodB"})
public class B extends HikariConfig {

    @DependsOn("mysqlEntityManagerFactory")
    @Bean
    public HikariDataSource mysqlDataSource() {
    }

    @DependsOn("mysqlTransactionManager")
    @Bean(name = "someEntityManager")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean mysqlEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
    }

    @Bean(name = "someTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager mysqlTransactionManager(@Qualifier("someEntityManager") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    }

}
```